# Rank groups using basic SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

Anyone would give me a hand on how to add a group column using basic SQL? I work with Teradata SQL Assistant.

My dataset is like this:

```
mydate      color     mytime
----------------------------
9/1/2017    red        1:00
9/1/2017    red        2:00
9/1/2017    red        3:00
9/1/2017    red        4:00
9/1/2017    yellow     5:00
9/1/2017    yellow     6:00
9/1/2017    red        7:00
9/1/2017    red        8:00
9/1/2017    yellow     9:00
9/1/2017    yellow    10:00
9/1/2017    yellow    11:00
9/1/2017    yellow    12:00
9/1/2017    red       13:00
9/1/2017    red       14:00
9/1/2017    red       15:00
9/1/2017    yellow    16:00
9/1/2017    yellow    17:00
```

My desired result (adding the column "mygroup"):

```
mydate      color  mygroup  mytime
----------------------------------
9/1/2017    red      1      1:00
9/1/2017    red      1      2:00
9/1/2017    red      1      3:00
9/1/2017    red      1      4:00
9/1/2017    yellow   2      5:00
9/1/2017    yellow   2      6:00
9/1/2017    red      3      7:00
9/1/2017    red      3      8:00
9/1/2017    yellow   4      9:00
9/1/2017    yellow   4     10:00
9/1/2017    yellow   4     11:00
9/1/2017    yellow   4     12:00
9/1/2017    red      5     13:00
9/1/2017    red      5     14:00
9/1/2017    red      5     15:00
9/1/2017    yellow   6     16:00
9/1/2017    yellow   6     17:00
```

Comment: Where does the value in the `mygroup` column come from? Need a little more information because I dont understand what criteria you're grouping by.

Comment: The group is based on color but comes in an order of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
   mydate
  ,color 
  ,mytime
   -- then create the group number
  ,sum(flag)
   over (order by mydate, mytime 
         rows unbounded preceding) as mygroup
from
 ( 
    select
       mydate
      ,color 
      ,mytime
      -- first: find the row where the color changes
      -- previous row is different from current row
      ,case when min(color)
                 over (order by mydate, mytime 
                       rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) = color 
            then 0
            else 1
       end as flag
    from mytable
 ) as dt
```

The `MIN(color)` calculation is an emulation of the `LAG` function which was not available in Teradata before TD16.10.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much dnoeth! This is exactly what I need! Thanks so very much!